# Specific the Visual C++ compiler in cmake

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-errors, cmake

I have Visual Studio 2015 community installed. I want to use cmake to compile using Visual Studio C++ compiler.

When run cmake command, I got this error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
```

How can I specific the path of VC++ compiler?

Comment: That answers said about create a C++ project in VS 2015, so that VS install C++ compiler and download C++ packgage, I haved them full installed before, I can create C++ project and run without have to install any addition things.

Comment: Did you try running cmake from a visual studio command prompt? Not sure if the community version has that. I usually do my cmake generation in a Visual Studio command prompt.

Comment: Yes, I ran it in VS command promt to, it's a .bat file which call cmake from inside. VS community have Developer command promt, the community have all functions of a professional version, so I don't think its because missing function of VS.

Comment: What generator are you specifying?

Comment: Is "generator" mean "compiler"? I am pretty confused.

Comment: `-G` specifies the generator: `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015"` and `cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"` work for me.

Comment: Could you give some extra help please? This is the git project of and .net native compiler project, https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr, I am following its documentation but when run the build.bat file I got that error. I don't know where to put the -G param in that build.bat :(

Comment: `build.cmd` has a `:GenVSSolution` label which calls `src/pal/tools/gen-buildsys-win.bat` and this batch script is already specifying the `-G` option, see line 32 and 34.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99750/discussion-between-verdana-and-james-adkison).

Comment: What's your CMake version? Older version don't know about VS 2015.

Comment: I am using the latest version 3.4.1